# Message Format when sent from browser to HTTPReceiver/JMSQueue - TIBCO

Tags: xml, tibco, tibco-business-works

I have a question: recently, I have learnt about integration of middleware and used TIBCO Designer to design my process.

I would like to ask what is the format of the message when it reaches the HTTPReceiver? Is it in string or XML directly?

Because in my labs, the activity after receiving the message from the HTTPReceiver is to Parse the XML.

Hence, I was wondering at which stage is the Message converted to an XML straight.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The output of HTTP Receiver can be either String or Binary. 
You need to transform this to an XML Format thus using the Parse XML pallete.

You can read more about this palette in this [TIBCO link](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.2.1/doc/html/GUID-3284CC4F-4BE9-469D-B002-E45FB10B723B.html) .